# How to convert body value then validate with RestAssured without extracting response

Tags: rest-assured

I have a String value being returned from restAssured that I want to convert to a DateTime then validate. One easy way to do this would be:

```
MockMvcResponse response = this.given
        .accept("application/json")
        .body(body)
        .when()
        .put(link)
        .then()
        .extract().response()

String jsonStr = response.asString()
Map json = strToJson(jsonStr)
assert(MyFixedDateTime.equals(new DateTime(json.dateAttr))
```

Is there a way to do this without extracting the response?

Answer (score 1):

Follow this [link](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#example-1---json)

I think you gonna need to do something similar:

```
this.given
    .accept("application/json")
    .body(body)
    .when()
    .put(link)
    .then().body("dateFieldName", equalTo(MyFixedDateTime.toString()))
```

Comment: This is close to what I want, but my issue with converting to a string is that the string values aren't equal (one has the 'Z' time zone designator and the other doesn't), though the dates they represent are equal.

Comment: well, you would need to convert your `MyFixedDateTime` into valid format without time zone symbol and make sure that the format the same as in the JSON property

Comment: Sure, but my question is more asking about a way you can refer to the value of the body field within the body tag itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the required value using JsonPath and convert the returned string to DateTime.

```
Response response = RestAssured.given ()
  .accept("application/json")
  .body(body)
  .when()
  .put(link);
JsonPath jsonPath = JsonPath.from (response.asString ());   
String date = jsonPath.get ("responseRoot.dateField"));
DateTime dt = new DateTime (date);
```

Comment: This seems to be very similar to extracting the response. I'm starting to wonder if this is the only way to play with the return value.

Comment: There are multiple ways but I feel this is much clean and readable way to get the response values.